# Can I use text shadow on a textarea without the shadow cutting off?

Tags: textarea, css

When I apply a text shadow to a text area, the shadow sharply cuts off.

[image]

```
<textarea placeholder="Type something"></textarea>
```

```
textarea {
    text-shadow: -5px -4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 5px 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Adding padding to textarea doesn't help. It just moves the cutoff shadow to another place. Is there any way to keep this same text shadow without it getting sharply cut off?

Here's a [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8Dx/2/)

Comment: You could `text-align:center`?

Comment: You can "cheat" it with `padding:12px`...

Comment: @Passerby That's not cheating, but the only solution :)

Comment: @Passerby That doesn't stop it from getting cut off. The text is moved to the right and there's still a sharp cutoff line where the padding ends.

Comment: @lala I said `padding:12px`, not `padding-left:12px`: http://jsfiddle.net/3v8Dx/4/

Comment: @Passerby I still see a sharp cutoff in both Chrome and Firefox. http://i.imgur.com/o1DdAcW.jpg

Comment: @lala Alright, just checked and Chrome 33 seems fine, but Firefox 27 renders like your screenshot. Let me think of something else...meanwhile, I suggest you add this info to your question so other potential answerers can be aware.

Comment: @Passery Thank you! It was in the question from the beginning but everyone seems to miss it, so I'm not sure if I should rephrase somehow. :-/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to style a placeholder like absolute and give it a z-index yet. Furthermore, the box-shadow porperty is not similar to i.e. a border since its width will not be added to the size of the element itself.

In your case, you could simply add some padding to your input.

Answer (score 0):

use only padding-left : 20px , problem solved :)

[Live example here >>](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8Dx/3/)

css{

```
textarea {
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: -5px -4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 5px 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 80px;
    padding-left:20px; 
}
```

Comment: But adding padding just moved the cutoff shadow to the right. It still has a sharp cutoff line.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this demos ant try it...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QsuKA/)

```
 textarea {
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: -5px -4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 5px 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 80px;
     height: 64px;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
}
```